# Alternative for regex.unescape in C# for quotes (")

Tags: c#, .net, regex

So i am facing a problem here which i am sure has a simple answer but i cannot seem to find it.

I am comparing string data from 2 tables using C# code
When the data is null or empty in both tables, i want the comparison to return "True" which basically means they are identical.

I am using string.IsNullorEmpty for checking null or empty conditions.
The problem is in one table, the string value is `""` while the other table has the same value escaped and is appearing as `"\"\""`

I assumed using `regex.unescape` will solve this but it does not seem to be working and i am getting an output that both the values are different causing problems.

One solution i figured out is directly checking if `str == "\"\""` for solving the problem.

But are there any cleaner options?

Comment: could you check on the `Length` of both strings being > 0 or == 0

Comment: It sounds like one string is actually two double quotes and not actually empty.  If you want two double quotes to be the equivalent of empty then you'll have to specifically check for it as you have indicated you already are.

Comment: @MethodMan: So i realized i can use string.length but i need to compare it value 2 and not 0 which again seems like using hard coded numbers which i generally try to avoid.

Comment: @juharr: Yes the strings are actually two double quotes but they evaluate to true when we use the function string.empty in C#.

Comment: @Shades `String.Empty` is not a function that you can evaluate... and if you compare (which is what I think you mean), a string containing two quotes vs string.Empty won't compare to true, never, ever. (that is: `"\"\"" == string.Empty` is false, always)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are mixing things here.

If your strings come from the same data source, then either all of them are escaped, or they are not (and if that's not the case, you have bigger problems than what you are stating).

So, if they are not escaped, and one of them contains `""`, and the other one contains `\"\"`, then they are not equal, one is 2 characters in length, and the other one is 4.

So I'm assuming that they are escaped and your first string is actually empty in the database (it doesn't contain any characters), and the second one is `\"\"`.

You can then use `Regex.Unescape` (**if** they are always escaped), but those two strings are not the same: one is empty, and the other one contains (once unescaped), `""`, so the first string contains no characters and the second one has two of them: no wonder they won't be compared equal.

Now, iff they are indeed escaped, it does not make sense that one contains `""`, because those characters should be escaped. And if this is not the case, then you have a very specific problem which is not what you asked for: you need to determine whether  your string comes escaped or not from the data source... and that's basically impossible unless there's a very specific set of rules which determine so.

If the data source contains randomly escaped or not strings, imagine your data source returns a string `\"\"`: how do you determine if the actual content is escaped and it means `{'"','"'}` (2 characters, each of them being a double quote), or if it isn't, and it's 4 characters, representing `{'\','"','\','"'}` *(one backslash, one double-quote, one backslash and one double-quote)*? There's just no way to tell unless you have a specification that determines those rules (or another field saying if the string is escaped or not).

So, back to your question: although you haven't put any code, my guess is that it is just not wrong: either your expectatives are what are wrong (you want `\"\"` to mean a string is empty, but it doesn't, because it just doesn't mean that), or your data is wrong.

Either way, there's no generic code solution to any of those... there's *specific* code solutions for *specific* cases (like the one you are showing), but not a generic one: with the info you gave in your question, it's just impossible

After all this babbling, now for a specific answer, if your table `A` contains unescaped strings, and your table `B` contains escaped strings:

```
stringFromTableA == Regex.Unescape(stringFromTableB)
```

Should return `true` if `stringFromTableA` contains `""` and `stringFromTableB` contains `\"\"`. [Check it](https://dotnetfiddle.net/7EUJhf). **Neither of those will be empty**, so `string.IsNullOrEmpty()` will return `false`

And an update: should you be checking those string values in the Visual Studio debugger, the debugger shows them escaped, so if you are seing `""` in one and `\"\"` in the other, then your first string is empty (and `string.IsNullOrEmpty` will return `true`), and your second string contains two double quotes: `string.IsNullOrEmpty` will return `false`, since it is not actually null or empty. And `Regex.Unescape` will do nothing on this case, since your string doesn't contain any `\` and there's nothing to escape, it's just the debugger showing those `\`'s.

Comment: The values for compare are coming from 2 different data sources. I am checking those string values in Visual Studio debugger. Maybe my expectations are inappropriate for this situation. I will be accepting this as an answer as it is well detailed

Comment: @Shades if you are checking the strings on the Visual Studio debugger, then you are seeing them escaped artificially. In the Visual Studio debugger, there's a magnifying glass button next to the string (at the far-end of the grid), which allows you to see the strings "raw", without escaping (it'll open up a window with a multiline textbox). There you can see the actual verbatim content of the string (and you'll see that it doesn't contain any ` \ ` characters, thus, it's not really escaped)

Comment: For example, I've made the content of my string as `My "Escaped" string` (no backslashes). This is how the standard debugger window shows that: http://snag.gy/dS2kx.jpg (notice the backslashes and the magnifying glass button). After clicking that button I can see the actual content: http://snag.gy/hoXVE.jpg